# WPF ComboBox with editable textbox as an item

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, textbox

I'm looking to have a combo box with only two items:

```
-----------
|  Other.. |
------------
|  TextBox |
------------
```

Text Box representing a physical textbox that can be editable and `Other..` being just a regular combobox item.

Can someone help me out on how I will need to edit it.

I have tried changing the Combbox.itemtemplate with a stackpanel and then adding a textbox, but it didn't show up and that also stops the chance of me having a regular combobox item in the control.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what the problem is, have you tried this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>Other</ComboBoxItem>
    <TextBox>TextBox</TextBox>
</ComboBox>
```

If this is not what you want, please explain what exactly you need...

---

*(The TextBox-item might be quite hard to select so giving it a label which can be clicked might be of interest)*

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>Normal Item</ComboBoxItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Other: " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox>Enter text...</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea it was that easy, and there I was confused in what I needed to do. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped :) As a side note, the ComboBox will create a ComboBoxItem around anything which is not a ComboBoxItem already, but the above syntax is not identical to `<ComboBoxItem><TextBox.../></ComboBoxItem>` as the `ComboBox.Items` collection will still directly expose the content instead of the ComboBoxItem if you let the ComboBox create this container for you.

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried setting `ComboBox.IsEditable = true`? Then you'll need just one item and the `ComboBox.Text` property.